# How to run specific code after n seconds on a video

Tags: python, azure, opencv

I am working on python3 and using Microsoft azure face API function 'CF.face.detect' to detect faces in a video.
I want to detect faces after every 1 second in the video that means run CF.face.detect once/second on video frame.

Please tell how to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many fps your video has, you could read the frames one by one and detect on every `n`-th frame, `n` being the number of fps of a video you're processing.

```
fps = x
cnt = 0

for f in get_frames():
  if cnt % fps == 0: 
    # run algorithm here
    cv.imwrite(f)
```

After you have gone through the video then you can run the algorithm. But I would suggest to run the algorithm in the loop and save the frame then, preferably with drawn result (squares for detection)

Comment: I can see FPS through this. Please tell me how to do "after every 1 second the current frame would be saved as test.jpg then I'll run my algo on it.                                                                  fps = vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
 #cv2.putText(frame, "{}: {:.2f}".format(fps), (30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 3) #if 1 ends
 print ('FPS : {0}'.format(fps))

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you can't do that because the video will wait for you to get the next frame. Just do the first suggestion as I wrote in edited answer: get first frame, save it, do a loop in which you get all the other frames from that second and when you are don with them, grab the next frame and save it and so on.

Comment: I get the first frame and saved it. Please tell how to get first frame of each second. I have total 29 frames per second

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, get the first one, if it's divisible by your fps (29) then process/save it, otherwise just get the next one. By divisible I mean if you divide it with fps (29) you have to get 0 remaining.